# dynamicly add to classpath in clojure repl to access java class files (pomegranate/add-classpath)

Tags: java, clojure, classpath, read-eval-print-loop

I have compiled class files in `shortScreen/out/production/classes/com/rsw/` and want to use them in a clojure repl. I think the hangup is on `add-classpath` but I'm unfamiliar with what should be happening. Or how to fix it.

```clj
(use '[cemerick.pomegranate :only (add-dependencies add-classpath)])
(import 'clojure.pprint)
(def myclasses "shortScreen/out/production/classes/com/rsw/")
; do i have the correct path?
(-> (clojure.java.io/file myclasses) (file-seq) (pprint)) ; shows many class files
(.exists (clojure.java.io/file myclasses "util.class")) ; true

; add the path
(add-classpath myclasses)

; but nothing like myclasses path in list
(def thiscp (.getURLs (java.lang.ClassLoader/getSystemClassLoader)))
(pprint thiscp)
(filter (fn [s] (re-seq #"out" s)) ;myclasses path should match "out"
     (for [x thiscp]
       (.toString x)))

; fails -- but not sure if this is the correct syntax anyway
(import 'com.rsw.util)
(util/msg "test")
```

Edit: **A reproducible example**

```sh
mkdir example && cd $_
# java code
cat > util.java << EOF
 package com.util;
 public class util {
 public static void msg(String a){
   System.out.println(a);
  }
 }
EOF

# clojure depends
cat > deps.edn << EOF
  {:deps {
    :alembic {:mvn/version "0.3.2"}
    :com.cemerick/pomegranate {:mvn/version "1.0.0"}
    }
  }
EOF

# compile java to class
javac util.java
ls # util.java util.class

# try to load in repl
clj

  (use '[cemerick.pomegranate :only (add-dependencies add-classpath)])
  (add-classpath (-> (java.io.File. ".") .getAbsolutePath))
  (import 'com.util.util)
  ; ClassNotFoundException com.util  java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:381)
```

Comment: `(add-classpath)` uses the context class loader while the system class loader might not be the same.

Comment: `(-> (Thread/currentThread) (.getContextClassLoader) (.getURLs) (seq) )` is nil? (nREPL with emacs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is old but as there are no accepted answers I figured it might be worth a response.

The java classloader system uses the classpath as a set of search roots and expects to find the actual classes under:

`<classpath element>/<directory hierarchy representing package name>/<class name>.class`

which in your case would look something like this:

```
example
└── com
    └── util
        ├── Util.class
        └── Util.java
```

i.e. it seems that in your example you are trying to load class `com.util.util` but putting the actual `.class` file in the root rather than under the appropriate directory hierarchy representing the `com.util` package name.

I ran your reproducible example and after this change things seem to work:

```clj
(import '[com.util Util])

=> com.util.Util
```

(I upper cased the class name, otherwise I ran your example as is)